# how to insert data.json to react component with all properties in interface (typescript)

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript, redux, interface

i has a productpage component, data.json and interface IProduct. Now, i want to using map function fetch all data in data.json to productpage component. The problem that i cant map data to productlist

[image: productpage component]

[image: interface IProduct]
[image: data.json]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm already fixed. I'm change data.json to data.tsx and export default data. i'm put the data.tsx in public folder. Expected can help someone else